# Sensory neurons, interneurons and motor neurons - recognizing the type of neuron at microscopy images

Tags: neuroscience

Is there a simple way to distinguish between sensory neurons and interneurons and motor neurons at the microscopic images?

I read a little bit about Open Connectome Project. Is there a possibility of automatic (computer - algorithmic) recognition of the aforementioned types of neurons?

Comment: Classifications are based on shape, number of connections, projections of axon and such. Thus there is definitely a possibility of automatic recognition if its not already being done.